# Exporting a Postgres Database to an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv

I have a PostgreSQL database at work that is a single table of data. The theme of the data is computers - things like physical location, MAC address, serial number, and computer name.

I need to get this data exported to an Excel spreadsheet. I have Perl with DBD::Pg loaded on a laptop, so a programmatic solution is possible if need be.

Should I process the whole thing line-by-line with a loop, or is there an easier way to get a CDL? Has anyone had any experience with doing this sort of thing successfully before?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the solution doesn't have to be programmatic, this should help: [archives.postgresql.org article](http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-interfaces/2003-04/msg00082.php)

Answer (score 3):

This is not really a programming answer, but this has already been programmed, if exporting to CSV is acceptable.

You can look into:

- using [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-copy.html),
- using the `\o` or `\copy` commands in [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/app-psql.html) (there's quite a lot of references if you google something like "psql export csv"),
- if you have a tool like pgAdmin, you can export the results of a query in File->Export...

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to a Mac then Navicat for PostgreSQL Lite will allow you to do exactly this and is available for free in the Mac App Store. It is really simple to use and has a great interface to setup the connection to the database and to browse to the information you need.